# Hash deployment environment to subnet

Tags: python, ansible

I've got

```
deployment: dev
subnet: "{{ hash(deployment) % 255 }}"
```

In my `group_vars/localhost` for setting up ec2 hosts. However, that gives me

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! ERROR! 'hash' is undefined"}
```

What's a better way to generate the subnet from the deployment environment?

Comment: Will the `ipaddr` filter help you? http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html

Comment: @udondan I want to generate the IP addresses from the `"dev"` string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved via

```
subnet: "{{ deployment|hash|int(base=16) % 255 }}"
```